LinkedIn comment API version control and request permission mismatch
I have been trying to set up an application that will work with the LinkedIn API. So far, authentication works correctly, CRUD operations on posts for my users and organization work correctly, and, as far as I can tell, I have the correct permissions for using socialActions, eg. w_member_social or w_organization_social. There is a note in their docs for the versioned api here (versioned or unversioned doesn't matter, this api deprecation warning exists on all pages) that these permissions will change due to deprecation
permission scope deprecation
but the new permissions are not allowed when requested as a scope in authentication.
@ns_social.expect(comment_model, validate=True)
@ns_social.doc('create_comment')
def post(self, object_urn):
    """Create a comment on a given URN"""
    data = request.json
    if unversioned:
        api_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2'
    else:
        api_url = current_app.config['BASE_API_URL']

    url = f"{api_url}/socialActions/{quote(data['object'])}/comments"
    
    headers = prepare_headers()

    if unversioned:
        del headers['LinkedIn-Version']
    
    print(url, headers, data)
    
    response = make_api_request(url, headers, data, method='CREATE')
    return jsonify(response)

Here's a little code snippet for the bot. Really it's just an internal route for handling a POST request,so nothing new. make_api_request handles requests and responses and errors, prepare-headers, unsuprisingly, prepares headers
However, when trying to make a comment with the deprecated permissions I get "{'status': 403, 'serviceErrorCode': 100, 'code': 'ACCESS_DENIED', 'message': 'Not enough permissions to access: partnerApiSocialActions.CREATE..."
To add to this, the different API versions have different endpoint permissions associated with same scopes, eg. w_member_social has different resources such as /rest/socialActions or /rest/reactions available to it depending on the LinkedIn-Version header
I have tried using https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ as suggested [by this user] (The LinkedIn Comments API doesn't work in the latest version) from this post but that resulted error 999 with this {'Date': 'Sat, 11 May 2024 10:59:19 GMT', 'X-Li-Fabric': 'prod-lva1', 'X-Li-Pop': 'prod-lva1-x', 'X-LI-Proto': 'http/1.1', 'X-LI-UUID': 'AAYYK4tCUhJ+deFNO/xL3Q==', 'Set-Cookie': 'denial-reason-code=5,2,30; Max-Age=5, denial-client-ip=79.140.148.156; Max-Age=5', 'Content-Length': '2109', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'} in the headers
All other versions of the API, that have the correct endpoints (202401 does not contain endpoints for /rest/socialActions), fail with the same 403 error
I have confirmed that the products are active and available and also tried generating new client secrets
Am I missing something about how to resolve this beaurocratic nightmare?
#linkedin
I tried varying requested scope, API version, authentication, request protocol, and more. I was expecting to be able to make comments as easily as I can make posts and shares

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The question is just about LinkedIns API not functioning as documented and the code is a POST, so there's ot much code to show, but ok (y)
